# Not getting the connection between the passing data from model and controller to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, scaffolding

i am deadly stuck at one place i tried scaffolding using various sites but now i am totally confused about the thing to do.

I have a project divided into there parts from them 2 are class libraries and one is main mvc project as shown here.[image: Image showing my project directory]

Now i added entity model in .Dal and i added references for each other as per needs. I tried to make a controller using scaffolding and it was success.
But the main problem is i cannot solve this error continuosly coming on running the project.

The error is this:[image: The error i am experiencing]

This is the method i am calling from controller as follows:
[image: Controller method]

The view page:
[image: The View page definitions of the controller]

I done this while adding controller with scaffolding:
[image: The options selected while adding controller]

Comment: Your question needs to include your code, not images of it. And you have not shown the correct view (the view you have shown does not cause that error (but its layout might)

Comment: what more i need to add?

Comment: Your code (not images of it). Somewhere your calling a view or partial view that has `@model LoginTable`, possibly using `@Html.Partial()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error clearly states that your view is expecting a different view Model & a list is being passed from controller. Crosscheck your code once & check the references for the view Model.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i was wrong at view of the _Layout page.
The error was because of i added a hard-coded line in _Layout page as shown below that is why i was getting this error of not getting the respective model.
The error causing view is: [image: The highlighted part is the error causing line]

Now when i removed this line from _Layout page it was working as expected.
**Thus i learned that the _Layout page is one masterpage of our application and remains consistent when used throughout the application**

**Thus the thing that cleared me is after view page is debugged the layout page is called at the end which is the base of all the views referring to it**